# Which equation to use for simple harmonic motion?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators

I recently started studying simple harmonic motion and I came across two equations for the displacement of a particle, as given in my textbook:

\begin{align}
y &= a\sin(\omega t +\phi)\\
x &= a\cos(\omega t+ \phi) \, .
\end{align}

I really have no clue when to use which one. It would help me a lot if someone could give an explanation on this.

Answer (score 4):

They're equivalent. You can always use either one. To convert between the two, use the basic trigonometric identity

$$\cos(\omega t+\phi)=\sin(\omega t+\phi-\pi/2)$$

Comment: I see, and will the signs of  change depending on whether the motion is clockwise or anticlockwise?

Comment: @UserKunal123 No, the sign of $\omega$ will change. $\phi$ defines the starting point of the oscillation.

Comment: I get it..but there is one more equation given in my book: y=asin(wt-). Isn't the sign of  changing here? And when do I use this equation? I apologize for not being clear.

Comment: For the equation $y=A\sin(\omega t-\phi)$, the starting position is positive if $\phi$ is positive. For the equation $y=A\sin(\omega t+\phi)$, the starting position is _negative_ if $\phi$ is positive. Once again, you can use either one.

Comment: So, can I use either of the two equations given in my main question, for both clockwise and anticlockwise cases? Or, would something change in the equations for each case?

Comment: @UserKunal123 Yes, the numbers you plug in to $\omega$ and $\phi$ would be different in every case, but you can use any of them.

Comment: I think my confusion is clear now. Thank you so much!